# Add vector world map to raster animation in R

Tags: r

I have created an animation with the `animate` function of the `raster` package and would like to add a vector map of the world on it.

This is my code where I create a raster brick from a 3D array of monthly mean temperatures before animating it:

```
r <- brick(ncols=nb.cols, nrows=nb.rows)
r <- setValues(r, monthly.mean)
animate(r)
```

The raster animation works great but how can I add a vector map of the world?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `addfun` argument

```
library(raster)
# example data
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
s <- stack(replicate(10, setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))
xy <- cbind(-180 + runif(10) * 360, -90 + runif(10) * 180)

# create a function to add some vector data
fun <- function() {
    points(xy, cex=2)
    points(xy, pch=3, col='red')
}

# use it
animate(s, addfun=fun)
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank you! both methods worked like a charm!

A quick answer for those interested:

With saveHTML:

```
require(animation)
require(rgdal)
require(raster)

countries <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="Countries")  # Shapefile of world countries

r <- brick(ncols=144, nrows=72)
r <- setValues(r, monthly.mean)          # monthly.mean is a 3D array 144x72x420

saveHTML({
  for(m in 1:420) {                      # serie of 420 months
    plot(r[[m]], zlim=c(min, max))       # min, max of the legend
    plot(countries, add=T)
  }
})
```

With FUN:

```
require(rgdal)
require(raster)

countries <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="Countries")

r <- brick(ncols=144, nrows=72)
r <- setValues(r, monthly.mean)

fun <- function() {
  plot(countries, add=T)
}

animate(r, zlim=c(min, max), addfun=fun)
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can, but you can use the `animation` package to create a web page animation with play/stop/loop controls etc.

You will have to write a function to draw each frame of your animation with the raster layer and the vector map, and then you stick that in the `saveHTML` function of the `animation` package.

Example (not tested):

```
saveHTML( { for(f in 1:12){plot(r[[i]]; plot(world, add=TRUE)} })
```

should create an HTML file and open your browser to view it. To make this example work you will need a `world` vector object in the same coordinate system. You might also want to set the `zlim` when you plot the raster so the scale doesn't change.

Comment: I'm trying all this. Thanks!