# r convert raster stack or brick to an animation

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I have downloaded some NetCDF files of land use scenario results from http://luh.umd.edu/data.shtml. Each file at this location has values for 11 land use types with annual values from 2015 to 2100.  I'd like to make an animated gif or movie that shows the changes over time. This seems like it should be straightforward but I've tried a variety of routes, none of which work, so I'm hoping for some that actually work. 
1. One approach involves creating a raster stack or brick of one of the land use variables using the stack or brick functions from the raster package. then using the raster animate function. Unfortunately, I get the following error message "animation of RasterLayer [stack, brick] objects not supported".

2. Another option is to convert each year of the land use data into a SpatialPixelDataFrame and then into a data.frame, use ggplot to create a gif and then combine the gifs into an animated gif. But this process seems extremely convoluted.

An R script that contains my current efforts to do this is [here](https://github.com/openmodelingfoundation/landuse/blob/master/R/importLUH2Data.R).

Answer (score 6):

Having a look through your code, I can make the code below work.

Basically, I'm making a big dataframe with data for all years.

```
mydf <- purrr::map_dfr(
  as.list(ncin.brick), 
  ~setNames(as.data.frame(as(., "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")), c('value', 'x', 'y')), 
  .id = 'year'
)

gg <- ggplot(
  mydf, 
  aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)
) +
  geom_sf(data = borders, fill = "transparent", color = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  ggthemes::theme_map()

gganim <- gg + transition_time(as.numeric(year)) #+ labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}")

gganim
```

The picture below is the result (animation is subtle).

[image]

Comment: The purrr code is great! And the rest of this works for me. But it takes a really, really long time to create the animation. Any suggestions to speed things up?

Comment: Took a long time for me too. Sorry, I'm not al that familiar with spatial data, and I don't really know where the bottleneck is here.

Answer (score 3):

Try `raster::animate()`, there are several incompatible animate functions across packages and this seems like a clash.

I usually animate using a loop to plot raster slices, and capture that using the animate package, e.g. with `saveHTML()`.

For ggplot2 see the gganimate package, but it doesn't scale well given the need to expand the data out.

Comment: I thought I had explicitly added the raster prefix but apparently not. Here is where the conflict is coming from `Attaching package: ‘gganimate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:raster’:

    animate`

Comment: Could you expand a bit on how you use saveHTML(). I tried the following `saveGIF(raster::animate(ncin.brick, pause = 1, n = 1), movie.name = "animation.gif")` but it's been running for at least 1/2 hour with no output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031890/add-vector-world-map-to-raster-animation-in-r has a good example of using saveHTML and by example saveGIF