# R raster: saving a movie created with animate to a file?

Tags: r, jquery-animate, raster

Is there a way to save (to a file) a movie created in the `raster` package?  I can make an animation that I'm quite satisfied with (happens to be a raster time series), and it displays nicely in the `RStudio` plots window, but I can't figure out how to save it as a movie. For example:

```
library(raster)

b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
raster::animate(b, n=1)
```

Is there a way to save this animation to a file?

Comment: Have you tried to save it as HTML? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031890/add-vector-world-map-to-raster-animation-in-r`

Comment: animation::saveHTML(raster::animate(b, n=1),htmlfile = file.path(mydir,"test" )) 

and the resulting file does not contain the plots (animation).

Comment: I found an adequate solution with the av package:

Comment: av_capture_graphics(
  raster::animate(b, n=1),
  output = file.path(mydir,"test.mp4" ),
  width = 720,
  height = 480,
  framerate = 1,
  vfilter = "null",
  audio = NULL,
  verbose = TRUE
)